# UltiSnips not work in vim:E887: Sorry,this command is disabled, the Python's site module could not be loaded

Tags: python, vim, anaconda, vim-plugin, ultisnips

OS: Windows 10

vim version: vim8.1

Plugin manager: vim-plug

I have used vim-plug to install the following plugins successfully:
[image: _vimrc]

I used Anaconda3 to create a new environment called VimEnv and equipped with the 32bit python2.7 version.
In cmd, I input:

> conda activate VimEnv
>
> gvim exa.tex

But once I type the key "i" and get into the insert mode, then I type anything would cause the error:
[image]
If I input

> :py import sys

It would also occur the error E887.

It seems that the problem is that the plugin cannot use python.

---

**Some other information I tried:** Before I used 32bit python, I used 64bit python and vim cannot find it(apper the error that cannot find python27.dll). I googled and find it should use 32bit python, then the error that cannot find python27.dll disappeared.

To input

> :version

in vim I get

> +python/dyn
>
> +python3/dyn

.

I also try to run gvim in 32bit python3.6 environment, but things get worse, when I input any character in insert mode, it just quit.